# Using gsub and mapply to remove a vector of words from another vector of words of different lengths

Tags: r, gsub, mapply

I have a vector of words I want to be removed from another vector of words. I'm using mapply and gsub, but am getting the error "longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter".

```
    sw_column <- c(stop_words$word)
head(sw_column)
[1] "a"         "a's"       "able"      "about"     "above"     "according"


x <- c(amplification.words, deamplification.words, negation.words)
head(x)
[1] "acute"      "acutely"    "certain"    "certainly"  "colossal"   "colossally"


stop_words_clean <- mapply(gsub, x, "", sw_column)
error message: longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

I want the all the words in x to be removed from sw_column. Note: not all the words in x appear in sw_column

Comment: Do you need `sw_column[sw_column %in% x] <- ''` ?

Comment: Maybe: `stop_words_clean <- setdiff(sw_column, x)`. Hard to know what your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, but `setdiff(x, y)` returns elements in "x" (the first argument) that are not in "y" (the second argument). So,

```
stop_words_clean <- setdiff(sw_column, x)
```

May be what you're after.

Example:

```
sw_column <- c("a", "a's","able","about", "above","according")
x <- c("a", "able", "above")

setdiff(sw_column, x)
#[1] "a's"       "about"     "according"
```

As for `gsub`, that function *modifies* elements of a character vector, which was not your stated objective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a text vector into another you can use the following code, I used some fictitious vectors to explain myself.

```
stop_words_example <- c("a", "a's", "able", "about", "above", "according")
x <- c("a", "a's", "able", "about", "above", "according", "acute", "acutely", "certain", "certainly", "colossal", "colossally")

x[!x %in% stop_words_example]

[1] "acute"      "acutely"    "certain"    "certainly"  "colossal"   "colossally"
```